# Кавычки при переспрашивании в прямой и мысленной речах: когда их нужно ставить, а когда нет?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, цитата, диалог

Подскажите, какое существует общее правило касательно оформления переспрашиваний в диалогах и при мысленном переспрашивании? У меня сложилось впечатление, что далеко не всегда нужны кавычки. Например, при вводном "говорит" цитата не закавычивается, хотя "Грамота.ру" поясняет, что здесь может работать правило, когда "говорит" употребляется не как вводное, а как сказуемое, и тогда кавычки нужны (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)). Особенно интересует, нужно ли закавычивать предложение, состоящее только из переспрашиваемых слов? Я так понял, что это факультативно, и в основном переспрашиваемое закавычивается, когда есть чёткое указание на "чужую" речь при помощи дополнительных слов наподобие "Что значит «грустно»?", "Это его «батенька»", "Говорит «покамест»" и т. д. Вот мои примеры, в 1-м переспрашивания непосредственно в диалоге, а во 2-м мысленные переспрашивания в несобственно-прямой речи. Как правильно?

**1-й пример**

*— Грустно тебе, погляжу?*

*— (")Грустно(")? С чего бы?*

Здесь нет дополнительных слов, которые чётко указывали бы на "чужую" речь, поэтому можно не закавычивать, верно?

*— Грустно тебе, погляжу?*

*— Грустно? С чего бы?*

**2-й пример**

*— Да ты, батенька, совсем с дуба рухнул, как погляжу.*

*Что? (")Батенька(")? (")С дуба рухнул(")? Что за тон у него такой... (")Батенька(") говорит. (")С дуба рухнул(") говорит. Ну совсем не понимает, что лепечет.*

Здесь в первых двух случаях также нет чёткого указания на цитату (предложения с переспрашиваниями состоят только из переспрашиваемых слов), поэтому можно не закавычивать? А вот в оставшихся случаях есть "говорит" в значении сказуемого, и закавычить надо, верно?

*— Да ты, батенька, совсем с дуба рухнул, как погляжу.*

*Что? Батенька? С дуба рухнул? Что за тон у него такой... "Батенька" говорит. "С дуба рухнул" говорит. Ну совсем не понимает, что лепечет.*

Но если это неверная логика, то на что тогда ориентироваться?

Comment: перестаньте постоянно вносить малозначительные изменения в свои вопросы, отчего они перемещаются в начало списка вопросов. Вы не один здесь. Апать темы на любом уважающем себя форуме запрещено.

Comment: Ну а что делать, если вопрос долго остаётся без ответа? Удалять его и спрашивать заново или как тогда положено?

Comment: Какой-то вы гиперактивный! Я думаю, народ уже от количества ваших вопросов раздражается. Возникает ощущение, что вы решили форумчан отыметь во все места по максимуму. И настырный ещё такой, назойливый... :) Кайф пропадает, гурманство...

Comment: У меня нет такой цели, просто ищу ответы на вопросы, которые возникают. А та же "Грамота.ру" молчит неделями, а то и месяцами, вот и хочется уже когда-нибудь да услышать обстоятельное мнение.

Comment: Понятно. А так... вы молодец, конечно!!! Никого не слушайте, делайте своё дело. Но в меру :)))

Comment: Спасибо))) Пока что вопросы кончились, но кто знает, надолго ли)))

Comment: Ничего не делать. Не отвечают в двух случаях: либо вопросы слишком сложны, либо ответы очевидны. Вот второе —про ваши. Я уже объяснял, что нет правил на каждый чих. Есть, к примеру, правило, что названия книг пишутся в кавычках. Есть правило, что частица 'то' присоединяется дефисом. Всё! Нет же, вы постоянно задалбываете апом соседнего вопроса и ещё удивляетесь, мол как же так, почему же не отвечают. С этим вопросом так же.

Comment: Я не филолог, и мне такие вещи не очевидны. Поэтому и хочется получить развёрнутый ответ, а в каких-то случаях, как в этом, чтобы подтвердили или опровергли мои догадки...

Comment: Всем хочется. Единственный легальный способ привлечь внимание к ушедшему вниз вопросу — это назначить за него награду баллами (они списываются с вашего рейтинга, называется 'объявить конкурс', кнопка под телом вопроса). Тогда, может, кто-то и не поленится писать развёрнутый ответ на простой вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрю, что это за штука такая с наградами.

Comment: @Катперкат ваш совет логически неисполним. Последовать совету "никого не слушать" = его нарушить.

Comment: Что логика? Жизнь намного сложнее. Она не квадратная. Тут есть тонкие намёки, дипломатия, политика, психология, юмор. Мы с Shi Komarishe др. др. поняли, а это - главное...

Comment: @ShiKomarishe Что-то я засомневалась. *Ну совсем не понимает, что **лепет.*** Вы какой глагол имеете в виду? Если "лепетать", то правильная форма *он лепечет*. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Да, "лепечет". Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что имеется у Розенталя ([Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160)).

> **5.** Если в последующей реплике повторяются слова из предыдущей реплики, принадлежащей другому лицу, причем они воспринимаются как чужой текст, то эти слова выделяются кавычками:
> а) Купавина. *Ах, это смешно наконец. Зачем юристом, когда ничего нет.*
> Лыняев. *Как **«ничего»?***
> Купавина. *Так, ничего, чистая бумага* (Остр.);
> б) Силан. *Пройдись малость, лучше тебе…*
> Курослепов. *Да, **«пройдись малость»!** Всё твоё рассмотрение…* (Остр.)

В первом примере, думаю, выделение кавычками не нужны, так как *грустно* можно считать ответом на вопрос (*Мне грустно?*), частью собственно слов собеседника.

*— Грустно тебе, погляжу?

— Грустно? С чего бы?*

> — Ну, мне пора. Покойнички-то мои, верно, беспокоятся — две ночи пропадаю. Все дела, дела...
> — И не страшно тебе на кладбище?
> — Чего же страшно? Напротив — компания приятная.
> — И не гадко?
> — Что ж такое — гадко? Конечно, если кто еще червивый и лезет к тебе... А которые долго лежат, подсохли... Что ж в нем гадкого? Из баб такие попадаются экземплярчики...
> [Г. В. Иванов. Петербургские зимы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dQufBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%E2%80%A6%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%98%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5?%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE?&source=bl&ots=UJ68T-NL9R&sig=ACfU3U0_AAT_j7UakferHHT6JVF325vcVA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZhJDmpbX5AhWjBxAIHUBTBdYQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%E2%80%A6%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%98%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%3F%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%3F&f=false)

Во втором примере повторяемые слова являются особенными, не присущими речи автора (поэтому он их удивленно и воссоздает). И отсутствие глаголов "говорит" никак не влияет на обрамление чудных для него слов кавычками. Считаю, что они нужны.

*— Да ты, батенька, совсем с дуба рухнул, как погляжу.

Что? "Батенька?" "С дуба рухнул?" Что за тон у него такой?!. "Батенька" говорит. "С дуба рухнул" говорит. Ну совсем не понимает, что лепечет.*

> — Что-то вы меня, папаша, больно утесняете, — вдруг плаксиво выговорил человек.
> Филипп Филиппович покраснел, очки сверкнули.
> — Кто это тут вам «папаша»?* Что это за фамильярности! Чтобы я больше не слыхал этого слова! Называть меня по имени и отчеству!
> Дерзкое выражение загорелось в человечке.
> — Да что вы все... То не плевать. То не кури. Туда не ходи... Что ж это на самом деле. Чисто как в трамвае. Что вы мне жить не даете?! И насчет «папаши» — это вы напрасно. Разве я вас просил мне операцию делать?
> <...>
> — При чем тут этот домком!
> — Как это при чем? Встречают, спрашивают, — когда ж ты, говорят, многоуважаемый, пропишешься?
> — Ах ты, господи, — уныло воскликнул Филипп Филиппович, — «встречаются, спрашивают»...** Воображаю, что вы им говорите. Ведь я же вам запрещал шляться по лестницам.
> — Что я, каторжный? — удивился человек, и сознание его правоты загорелось у него даже в рубине. — Как это так «шляться»? Довольно обидны ваши слова. Я хожу, как все люди.
> М. А. Булгаков. Собачье сердце

Стоит отметить, что указанные слова (со звездочками) в некоторых изданиях повести оформлены без кавычек. Чаще всего, конечно, автор сам принимает решение, ставить или не ставить кавычки, но иногда (особенно если произведению почти сто лет) — тот или иной корректор.

Comment: Ну где вы все?.. :(